# How to access the /usr/share/javascript/jquery/ files?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am now using jquery and jalert on multiple web pages.  Currently each had its on version of the j files.  However; I wanted to have one location where all the j and their css files could be located in one location and use that.  I asked the SA to see if jquery and jalert were already installed as part of the RedHat OS bundle and he said jquery was already installed at /usr/share/javascript/jquery/.  I know that these files are suppose to be located under the /var/www/html directory tree to be usable but he said no, just change you path to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/usr/share/javascript/jquery/latest/jquery.js">`

But of course it doesn't work.  I am thinking that I will have to make a directory and either copy in or make link out to the /var/www/html/jquery/latest files, but I am not sure what the correct style is.

I googled, but all I see are people saying to have a local copy with their project or put in a url that will use some other site's jquery files.

So my question is, how do you use these installed j/css files that are located outside of the /var/www/html tree?

Comment: While it is possible with a symlink if you are on a linux machine, dont do it. There is no reason why you would want to refer to a common folder for custom libraries. They take up very little space and the problems arising when debugging such a setup would be large.

Comment: There is likely a reason that all those people are saying to use a local copy or to use a CDN. Perhaps instead of forging ahead on a path no one else is using, you listen to what other people are saying?

Comment: j query files are not "custom" libraries, they are a collection library of functions what make using html easier.  Having 20 plus copies everywhere and is a maintenance problem.  I am trying understand what the correct style to handle this.  RH installed these files there for a reason, if nothing else so you can copy them somewhere else.  Please try and stay focused on the question.